# Golang cannot write file into directory

Tags: go, io

**Situation:**

I'm trying to write a file into a directory, like shown as follows:

```
func (p *Page) Save() error {
    filepath := DerivePath(p.Title)
    fmt.Println(filepath)
    content, _ := json.MarshalIndent(p, "", "    ")
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(filepath, content, 0600)
    return err
}
```

**Problem:**

The following error occurs in line 5:

> open data/Testpage.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

- I already tried to create the file before writing with `os.Create`, but it doesn't work either.
- Loading from the `data` directory works just fine. Only writing *new* files into the directory fails.

***Additional information:***

My project structure is as follows:

```
│   .gitignore
│   .project
│
├───bin
│       main.exe
│
├───data
│       Welcome.json
│
├───pkg
│   └───windows_amd64
│           page.a
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │       main.go
│   │
│   └───page
│           page.go
│           page_test.go
│
└───templates
        view.html
```

As mentioned above, *reading* `data/Welcome.json` works just fine (by using `io/ioutils.ReadFile`).
The source is available on https://gitlab.com/thyaris/Wiki.

Executing `D:\GitWorkspaces\Wiki\wiki>go test -v page` writes the following output:

```
=== RUN   TestSave
data/Testpage.json
--- FAIL: TestSave (0.00s)
        page_test.go:15: open data/Testpage.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
        page_test.go:19: 'Testpage.json' was not created
=== RUN   TestLoadPage
--- FAIL: TestLoadPage (0.00s)
        page_test.go:26: Error while loading
        page_test.go:32: File content did not match
=== RUN   TestDelete
--- PASS: TestDelete (0.00s)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    page    0.094s
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions for that directory?

Comment: I am working on windows, so I thought this should not be a problem. I assumed this also because it worked when I was not yet writing into the `data` directory.

Comment: I just checked the permissions, I have permission to read and write files in the `data` directory

Comment: What about using "./data/" instead of "data/"? Assuming that the "data" directory is in the current working directory of course.

Comment: Produces the same error, but with `./data/Testpage.json`

Comment: *shrug* I cant see anything wrong with it... Two things to try: A) Write directly to the current working directory, just to see what happens B) use `0666` as the permissions (shouldn't make any difference on Windows).

Comment: Doesn't change anything (0666), sorry :/

Comment: Writing it into the working directory creates the file in `src/page/`, but that's just not the directory I need it to be in

Comment: There's your problem. Your working directory is not where you expected it. You need to use "../../data/" while testing, and possibly something similar normally. If this works I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: fixed as of 3095e1b277d7e3175d0d1f4cb72a23291ced9e74

Comment: you can add it as an answer, thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that the test engine is not running your executable with the working directory you expect. Instead of using the working directory defined by your shell or IDE, it is setting it to the source directory of the code being tested. (I had this bite me too once, long ago :) I had almost forgotten about that...)

The simple solution is to change `DerivePath` so that you can set the prefix externally, then change it to a the path you need at the beginning of your tests. There are other (possibly better?) solutions of course.

Comment: I fixed by creating the data directory in the tests and deleting it afterwards. I will change this sometime.

Comment: Same here on windows 10 but using Linux subsystem with ubuntu installed.  I have to have my code delete the directory and then recreate the directory before I can create the file again.  Otherwise it says it creates the file without error but no file exists.  also it never returns a file does not exists .